# Difference between cv::normalize and Mat.convertTo when converting float 32 bit Mat to 8 bit unsigned Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am a bit puzzle and confused over what is the difference between the 2 function when converting a 32 bit float image to unsigned 8 bit image

Mat.convertTo

```
A.convertTo(B,CV_8U,255.0/(Max-Min),-255.0*Min/(Max-Min));
```

cv::normalize

```
cv::normalize(A,B,0,255, CV_MINMAX, CV_8U)
```

with A being 32 bit Mat and B being 8 bit uchar

What is the difference between the two? I have only know that convertTo involved a saturate_cast which cast the scaled B data to the data type (for example in my case to uchar, if scaled value is over 255 will be cast to 255 (which is quite impossible to happen in this case...)

Comment: For one, the call to `normalize` is much more readable.

Comment: Keep one question per question -- i'd suggest to put the question about `+- inf` into a separate post (and removing that bit from this one).

Comment: Other than that, you'd really have to go and compare the implementation of both functions (and there are several using different types of optimization) step-by-step. Without doing that, I wouldn't really expect both to produce identical output for all the possible inputs....but the differences aren't likely to be significant.

Comment: @DanMašek the other differences I found is that convertTo can use a mask which is not too useful for my case

Comment: I think you meant `normalize` regarding the mask (it happens :) ). Digging through the code a bit, it appears that `normalize` in this case first searches for actual min/max and then calls `convertTo`. Write a little performance test to see which one's better. If you already know the min/max, the `convertTo` variant might be faster. In that case, I'd wrap in a short function whose name expresses the intent better.